# Unexpected token ':' using node-webvtt parser package unsure reason of the error?

Tags: node.js, webvtt

Hey I am trying to parse a webvtt file in javascript and I wrapped the process in a try catch and it throws this error at me unsure why. Would appreciate any insight. I am using the node-webvtt package [node-webvtt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-webvtt).

I have the full vtt file but decided to just take the first example from it and put it as a string. I have tried passing in the whole file and still get the same error. I think I might have structured the try catch incorrectly but I still got the same error not using a try catch block.

The block of code:

```
const parsed = (err) => {
    try{
        webvtt.parse(`WEBVTT 


1
00:02:57,642 --> 00:02:58,672
Happy Monday, everybody.`);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: You must separate the milliseconds with a dot, not with a comma, for example, `00:02:57.642 --> 00:02:58.672`.

Comment: Yes, I was seeing that but it does not fix the token error with the colon.

Comment: The `err` parameter in your `parsed` function has no effect, how do you invoke the function?

Comment: Just like that but maybe I am doing it wrong. The package creator said to wrap the .parse function in a try catch. Do you have a suggestion for formatting the try catch block?

Comment: The try-catch-block is OK, but the `parsed` function needs no parameter. How do you invoke the function? It returns nothing.